How to use ML-KEM/Kyber for encrypting data using PublicKey and decrypting data using PrivateKey
I am learning how to use Post quantum cryptography with Java. The vendor implementation is provided by BouncyCastle version 1.78.1. In short, I'm using a  BouncyCastlePQCProvider to obtain a Key Pair of specification Kyber1024.
static
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastlePQCProvider());
    }
    
    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Kyber","BCPQC");
            kpg.initialize(KyberParameterSpec.kyber1024);
            return kpg.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }
    
    public static byte[] encryptData(byte[] data, PublicKey publicKey)
    {
        Cipher cipher=null;
        try
        {
            cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Kyber", "BCPQC");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(data);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }
    
    public static byte[] decryptData(byte[] encryptedData, PrivateKey privateKey)
    {
        Cipher cipher=null;
        try
        {
            cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Kyber", "BCPQC");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyPair keyPair=generateKeyPair();
        byte[] publicKeyData=keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
        byte[] privateKeyData=keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
        String publicKeyHex=Hex.toHexString(publicKeyData);
        String privateKeyHex=Hex.toHexString(privateKeyData);
        System.out.println("Public key length " + keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded().length + " format " + keyPair.getPublic().getFormat() + " algorithm " + keyPair.getPublic().getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("Public Key ");
        System.out.println(publicKeyHex);
        System.out.println("Private key length " + keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded().length + " format " + keyPair.getPrivate().getFormat() + " algorithm " + keyPair.getPrivate().getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("Private Key ");
        System.out.println(privateKeyHex);
        String message="Hello World!";
        byte[] encryptedData=encryptData(message.getBytes(), keyPair.getPublic());
        String encryptedDataStr=DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encryptedData);
        System.out.println("encrypted:" + encryptedDataStr);
        byte[] decryptedData=decryptData(encryptedData, keyPair.getPrivate());
        String decrtyptedDataStr=new String(decryptedData);
        System.out.println("decrypted:" + decrtyptedDataStr);
    }

However when running this code, getting some exceptions during encryption, getting Cipher only valid for wrapping/unwrapping exception
java.security.InvalidParameterException: Cipher only valid for wrapping/unwrapping
What am I doing wrong?

Exactly as it says; Kyber is a KEM = Key Encapsulation Mechanism which securely conveys/shares a key not data; in the JCA API this is handled as 'key wrap' (KW) and unwrap although technically KEM is not exactly the same thing as KW. You use the KEM to share a key (often called a 'working' key or DEK = Data Encryption Key for clarity) and use that key with a symmetric (not publickey) encryption algorithm like AES to encrypt (and decrypt) the data.
